# Access keys and values from map inside a List in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In my API call I store the keys and the values from a map inside a list. I want to access these keys and values in my ListView and display them in Text in my widget. How can I do that?

Api request

```
Future<List<Presence>> getPresencesByAthleteId(
      int depId, int teamId, int? id, context)  async {
        try {
          final response = await http.get(
              Uri.parse(
                  '$uri/get-presences-by-athlete-id?depId=$depId&teamId=$teamId&id=$id'),
              headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ...',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
              });
          print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
          print('Response body: ${response.body}');
    
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            if (response.body.isNotEmpty) {
              print('response.body.isNotEmpty');
              Map map = json.decode(response.body);
              List<Presence>? presencesList = [];
              map.forEach((key, value) {
                presencesList.add(Presence(
                    date: map.entries.first.key, count: map.entries.first.value));
                print('$key,$value');
              });
              return presencesList.toList();
            } else if (response.body.isEmpty) {
              print('response.body.isEmpty');
            }
          }
        } catch (e) {
          logger.e(e.toString());
        }
        return getPresencesByAthleteId(depId, teamId, id, context);
      }
```

My ListView

```
child: FutureBuilder<List<Presence>>(
                                                                                    future: getPresencesByAthleteId(_athlete[i].department!.id, widget._team.teamKey!.teamId, _athlete[i].id, context),
                                                                                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                                                                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                                                                        return ListView.builder(
                                                                                            shrinkWrap: true,
                                                                                            primary: true,
                                                                                            physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                                                                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                                                                            cacheExtent: 34,
                                                                                            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                                                                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                                                                              return ListTile(
                                                                                                title: Column(
                                                                                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                                                                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                                                                  children: [
                                                                                                    Row(
                                                                                                      children: [
                                                                                                        Text('${(index + 1).toString()}.'),
                                                                                                        const SizedBox(
                                                                                                          width: 5,
                                                                                                        ),
                                                                                                        Text(snapshot.data[index].toString()),
                                                                                                        const SizedBox(
                                                                                                          width: 20,
                                                                                                        ),
                                                                                                        Text(
                                                                                                          '{presencesList[index]',
                                                                                                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                                                                                                        )
                                                                                                      ],
                                                                                                    )
                                                                                                  ],
                                                                                                ),
                                                                                              );
                                                                                            });
                                                                                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                                                                        logger.e('${snapshot.error}');
                                                                                      }
                                                                                      return const Center(
                                                                                        heightFactor: 20,
                                                                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),
                                                                                      );
                                                                                    })
```

My Presence model

```
class Presence {
  String date;
  int count;

  Presence({required this.date, required this.count});
  factory Presence.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Presence(
        date: json['date'],
        count: json['count'] as int,
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "date": date,
        "count": count,
      };
}
```

The api from Postman that is the map that I store in my list

```
{
"10-11-2022":1,
"9-11-2022":4,
"7-11-2022":1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Text(snapshot.data[index].toString()),
```

You can simply do

```
Text(snapshot.data[index].date),
```

or

```
Text(snapshot.data[index].count.toString()),
```